# How to get rid of http errors and network errors in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I used VS 2022 to build API to take information and now it is using by the clients.

The controller class and the action method are shown here:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ABCController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Unit), 200)]
    public async Task<object[]> MoreDetails(SearchInfo sc)
    {
         Error error = new Error(1, "");

         Unit[] units = null;
         bool authavail = true;

         try
         {
             if (CheckPassword())
             {
                    MoreDetailsInfo lobjSearch = new MoreDetailsInfo (this._iconfiguration);

                    if (this._iconfiguration["trackid"] == "1")
                    {
                        authavail = lobjSearch.Ischeck(sc);
                    }

                    if (authavail)
                    {
                        units = lobjSearch.GetInfo(sc);

                        if (units != null && units.Length == 1)
                        {
                            if (units[0].IsGatewayError)
                            {
                                Error[] arrError = new Error[1];
                                arrError[0] = new Error();
                                arrError[0].ErrorNumber = -3;
                                arrError[0].ErrorMessage = "Error in response";

                                return arrError;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (units == null)
                        {
                            Error[] arrError = new Error[1];
                            arrError[0] = new Error();
                            arrError[0].ErrorMessage = "unable to take availabilities";

                            return arrError;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error[] arrError = new Error[1];
                        arrError[0] = new Error();
                        arrError[0].ErrorMessage = "Invalid destination!";

                        return arrError;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Error[] arrError = new Error[1];
                    arrError[0] = new Error();
                    arrError[0].ErrorNumber = -3;
                    arrError[0].ErrorMessage = "Authentication failed...";

                    return arrError;
                } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return units;
    }
}
```

But the clients informed me that they are taking network errors and http errors. How do I sort out those issues?

What steps should I need to perform?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the Unit

Comment: Could you please tell me which network errors or http errors they faced? 500 or 404 or else? You should post the details error message then we could continue working on it.